# Error 3194 while restoring jailbroken iPod touch 4g

Tags: itunes, restore, ipod, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I'm trying to restore my Jailbroken iPod touch from ipsw file, but at the end of restoring process, when itunes going to verify.
[image]

 The `error 3194` occurs.
[image]

I've also took these steps which apple support recommends on the following link: 
[Error 3194, Error 17, or "This device isn't eligible for the requested build"](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4451)
In addition, I'm doing this on my personal network at home which I have internet indeed and I can load apple website. I've tested it through Normal, VPN and Proxy connections too. But still no success.

- **PC OS**: `Windows 8`
- **iTunes version**: `11.1.5.5`
- **iPod model**: `iPod Touch 4G 32GB`
- **Jailbroken iOS version installed on iPod currently**: `6.1 (10B144)`
- **iOS version that I want to restore the iPod to**: `6.0.1 (10A523)` or `6.1.3 (10B329)` or  `6.0.1 (10A523)` or `6.1.6 (10B500)` (I've tested all ispw files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that all Apple-related entries are removed from your hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, then put the device in DFU mode and restore it.

1. Connect the device to your computer and turn it off.
2. Hold the power button and the home button together for 10 seconds, then release the power button but keep holding the home button.
3. Keep holding home further and a message should appear in iTunes telling you that the connected device must be restored.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation. You've got the bounty within 16 hours.

Comment: Just a question I did restoring because my iPod didn't detect any networks (It turns on). But after restoring still it's not fixed. Do you have any idea what causes this problem? Is it possible that this problem is about wifi chipset?

Comment: @Siamak I don't know — feel free to ask a separate question though

Answer (score 1):

Siamak - Here are the things I would try in order to resolve this issue:

1. If you have another iPod/iPhone sync cable, try to do the restore using a different cable to remove the cable as the source of the issue.
2. In Windows, create a temporary user account with administrative rights.   After you create the account, login using that account and try to restore your iPod.   This *should* eliminate any corruption issues in regard to iTunes, the IPSW file and your primary account.
3. Make sure you have totally disabled your Windows firewall.  Here is an article that explains how to do that http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=104&vw=1&articleid=27292
4. Connect to a public wireless network (like at a starbucks) and try to download the IPSW and restore using that connection.
5. Change the physical USB port you are using to do the restore.   Many older desktops (although I think you said back on your post on SU that you were using a Windows 8 laptop) will have USB 1.1 ports, which can cause issues with restoring your iPod.
6. Find a another computer that you can download and install iTunes on and try to restore using that computer.    I would reccomend not trying this from your own home if possible (ask a friend) because the error you are getting is due to not being able to contact the iTunes update servers (for whatever reason).

The [KB support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4451) from apple clearly states the following:

> Errors 1639, 3000-3020, and 3100-3999 (with the exception of 3194) are
>   sometimes caused by your network settings. If your computer uses a
>   managed network, refer to your network administrator. Proxies,
>   firewalls, and other network security measures can cause these errors.
>   If necessary, find a different network connection to restore the
>   device. For example, if you're restoring at work, try to restore at
>   home or on a friend's computer and network.

I know you had said previously that you had tried the suggested fixes in the KB article, just want to be sure you attempted this part of the article

> Address TCP/IP filtering, firewall, or security software
>   If you have TCP/IP filtering, firewall, or security software installed on your
>   computer, follow these steps.
>
> Follow these steps to configure or temporarily uninstall your security
>   software. Bypass your Internet router. Some routers might block iTunes
>   from accessing the update server. If you're using a router that isn't
>   manufactured by Apple, try these steps.
>
> 1. Disconnect from your wired or wireless router.
> 2. Use an Ethernet cable to connect directly to your modem.
> 3. Restart your computer and modem. Contact your Internet service provider for
>      instructions on using your modem.
>
> Be sure you have a
>   working Internet connection by visiting www.apple.com. 
>   See these steps
>   for help or contact your Internet service provider. If your Internet
>   connection is working, try to update or restore your iOS device again.

Hopefully one of those suggestions will allow you to restore your iPod.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, But none of the above steps helped me to solve the error. I really confused. Why restoring iPod device is too confusing and difficult.

Comment: You get the same error even if you do this on another computer????  What version are you trying to update to?

Comment: Yeap, I've tried on my laptop. About the versions look back into the question. I've updated it. Thanks.